# Lemma on infinitely generated projective modules

Tags: ring-theory, modules, projective-module

Is it true that every finitely generated submodule of a non-finitely generated projective over a (not necessarily commutative!) ring is contained in a proper summand?

(Ideally there's a standard reference for this... :) )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been answered on MathOverflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72788/lemma-on-infinitely-generated-projective-modules).